# variable defined but need to make it so the variable can be multiple values

Tags: oracle-apex

without adding a ton of code in here. I have an APEX application where I have a select list, where I want to select multiple codes from that list, and in return they populate a chart. I have it working where i can select one code, and it populates, but not sure how to make it so i can select two values.

For example (not real data or full query)

Select list of numbers: (these are defined as the variable p_number).

```
1234
2345
3456
4567
```

I want to select 1234 and 4567.

I have the variable defined in my query

p_number           IN VARCHAR2,

also have that select_all_3d defined as:

c_select_all_3D   VARCHAR2 (50) := NULL;

code for defined variable

```
    IF p_number IS NULL
    THEN
        c_select_all_3D := NULL;
    ELSE
        c_select_all_3D := ' and number = ''' || p_number || '''';
    END IF;
```

Would i add something so that last line of code would have something like number in or number contains that way it picks up both the variables i selected?

Comment: You first should settle on a way to pass multiple values to your procedure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select multiple values, then do exactly that: select list item allows you to enable "Select multiple values". Once you do that, item's value will contain selected values separated by colon sign, e.g. `1234:4567`.

You'd get the same result with a Shuttle item as well.

If you want to do something with such values, you'll have to split that column into rows. There are a few options to do that; when we're dealing with Apex, see `apex_string.string_to_table`.

On the other hand, if you'll always have only two values, you could even

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1234:4567' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '^\d+') first_value,
  4         regexp_substr(col, '\d+$') second_value
  5  from test;

FIRS SECO
---- ----
1234 4567

SQL>
```

Comment: looking into the APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE option. I am new to sql/APEX so kind of getting confused when I was looking up what this does, As far as implementing this, is this something that would go in a Dynamic Action in the APEX workspace on the page, or is the APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE kept in the procedure I am calling where I would be passing these values to?

Comment: Any option you choose, it would be used **later**, when you'd want to do something with those "multiple values" stored into the same item. That might be a report, for example.